# How to See All Columns or Wrap all Data within a Scaled Constraint for Viewing and/or Search-ability

Tags: r, shiny, dt

So I have a problem right now where I have datatables that are being rendered within a tabBox nested within tabPanels, and they are not showing all of the available columns to my users.

I have tried setting width and height equal to auto...I haven't tried much else.

```
              tabBox(
                                tabPanel("VW Output",
                                        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2", width = "auto", height = "auto")
                                        ),
                                tabPanel("VW DEMO",
                                        DT::dataTableOutput("vw_demo", width = "auto", height = "auto")
                                )
                              )
```

The actual result will show all of the data columns the pictures with the green columns are the ones that I am pulling from the googlesheet. And I am defining the data frames from google sheets with the Library(googlesheets) package for R.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFnj4.png)

[image]

[image]